# AWS Appium Project Package

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

I see below error while packaging appium project for AWS.
Unknown lifecycle phase `--DskipTests=true`. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format

Note:

1. Executing packaging command on mac terminal
2. Tried both `--DskipTests=true` & `-DskipTests=true` (see same error for both)

Looking forward for some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

I have seen this error when users copy-paste the command from the documentation.
We are working on updating this as there seems to be some unknown characters that get introduced.

Users have got this to work by deleting -DskipTests=true and typing it instead of copy pasting it.

Since you are on a Mac terminal you will need to use a single dash '-' for the parameter.

Apologies for the inconvenience.

Hope this helps.